# Некорректно создается окно FXML

Tags: java, gui, javafx, fxml

дело в том, что я делаю программу на javafx, когда я нажимаю определенную кнопку, то должно отобразиться другое окно, но дело в том, что это окно не всегда корректно подгружается из fxml, иногда загружается белое окно, но если развернуть программу на весь экран, а потом обратно восстановить исходные размеры окна, то форма оказывается загрузилась из fxml, но я не могу взаимодействовать с TextField.
Как решить эту проблему

Везде подобный код в контроллерах:

```
signup_sign_btn.getScene().getWindow().hide();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/auth.fxml"));
try {
    loader.load();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Parent root = loader.getRoot();
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("MyWin");
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.showAndWait();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что нужно использовать `stage.show();` вместо `stage.showAndWait();`